# Images not displayed in Firefox

Tags: support, images, firefox

Firefox 16.0.2 on Windows 7 is not displaying embedded images for me; they do display on the current version of Chrome. This behavior started within the last 24 hours, at about the same time as the modified display of new questions, new answers, and comments that was in effect for a while.

Comment: I can't reproduce using the same Firefox on Windows 7. Have you tried disabling all your extensions to make sure they are not responsible?

Comment: @MadScientist: Thanks. It was Adblock Plus, though I’m damned if I know how it happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to Mad Scientist: I’ve no idea how it happened, since I’ve not added any filters to the basic ones, but Adblock Plus was blocking the images.